# Crystal report not showing

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I created a crystal report and after running it was outputting all the details as required. am surprised now that when I run the same report now the report is showing blank fields with no data below is my code.
Try

```
    Dim rpt As New rptCheckoutNewReceipt 'The report you created.
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim MyCommand, MyCommand1, MyCommand2, MyCommand3, MyCommand4, MyCommand5 As New SqlCommand()
    Dim myDA, myDA1, myDA2, myDA3, myDA4, myDA5 As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim myDS As New DataSet 'The DataSet you created.
    Dim pdfFile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Report.Pdf"
    myConnection = New SqlConnection(cs)
    MyCommand.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand1.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand2.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand3.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand4.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand5.Connection = myConnection
    MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CheckInTime,CheckOutTime, OtherCharge, Room.R_ID, Room.RoomNo, Room.PlanCode, Room.RoomType, Room.MaxNoOfAdults, Room.MaxNoOfKids, Room.Active, CheckIN_Room.Cin_Id, CheckIN_Room.GuestID,CheckIN_Room.RoomID, CheckIN_Room.RoomCharges, CheckIN_Room.DateIN, CheckIN_Room.DateOUT, CheckIN_Room.NoOfDays, CheckIN_Room.NoOfMales, CheckIN_Room.NoOfFemales,  CheckIN_Room.NoOfKids, CheckIN_Room.NoOfExtraBed, CheckIN_Room.NoOfExtraPerson, CheckIN_Room.RoomOrderCharges, CheckIN_Room.ExtraPersonCharges, CheckIN_Room.TotalRoomCharges, CheckIN_Room.ExtraBedCharges, CheckIN_Room.OtherCharges, CheckIN_Room.DiscountPer, CheckIN_Room.DiscountAmount, CheckIN_Room.STPer, CheckIN_Room.STAmount, CheckIN_Room.LuxuryTaxPer, CheckIN_Room.LuxuryTaxAmount, CheckIN_Room.SubTotal, CheckIN_Room.GrandTotal, CheckIN_Room.TotalPaid, CheckIN_Room.Balance, CheckIN_Room.Status, CheckIN_Room.Notes, Guest.ID, Guest.GuestID AS Expr2, Guest.GuestName, Guest.Address, Guest.City, Guest.Country, Guest.ContactNo, Guest.Gender, Guest.Occupation, Guest.Religion, Guest.Email, Guest.IDType, Guest.IDNumber,  Guest.Pic1, Guest.Pic2, Guest.pic3, Guest.Notes AS Expr3, Guest.Company, Guest.Model, Guest.VehicleNo, Guest.Color FROM Room INNER JOIN CheckIN_Room ON Room.R_ID = CheckIN_Room.RoomID INNER JOIN Guest ON CheckIN_Room.GuestID = Guest.ID where Status='Checked Out' and Cin_ID=" & txtCheckInID.Text & ""
    MyCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT * from Hotel"
    MyCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT * from Currency"
    MyCommand3.CommandText = "SELECT Laundry_BillInfo.Id, Laundry_BillInfo.BillNo, Laundry_BillInfo.BillDate, Laundry_BillInfo.CheckInID, Laundry_BillInfo.GrandTotal, Laundry_BillInfo.PaymentMode, Laundry_BillInfo.TotalPayment,Laundry_BillInfo.PaymentDue, Laundry_BillInfo.LB_Status, LaundryServices.LS_Id, LaundryServices.BillID, LaundryServices.Service, LaundryServices.Rate, LaundryServices.Qty, LaundryServices.TotalAmount,CheckIN_Room.Cin_Id, CheckIN_Room.GuestID, CheckIN_Room.RoomID, CheckIN_Room.RoomCharges, CheckIN_Room.DateIN, CheckIN_Room.DateOUT, CheckIN_Room.NoOfDays, CheckIN_Room.NoOfMales, CheckIN_Room.NoOfFemales, CheckIN_Room.NoOfKids, CheckIN_Room.NoOfExtraBed, CheckIN_Room.NoOfExtraPerson, CheckIN_Room.RoomOrderCharges, CheckIN_Room.ExtraPersonCharges,CheckIN_Room.TotalRoomCharges, CheckIN_Room.ExtraBedCharges, CheckIN_Room.OtherCharges, CheckIN_Room.DiscountPer, CheckIN_Room.DiscountAmount, CheckIN_Room.STPer,CheckIN_Room.STAmount, CheckIN_Room.LuxuryTaxPer, CheckIN_Room.LuxuryTaxAmount, CheckIN_Room.SubTotal, CheckIN_Room.GrandTotal AS Expr1, CheckIN_Room.TotalPaid, CheckIN_Room.Balance,CheckIN_Room.Status, CheckIN_Room.Notes FROM Laundry_BillInfo INNER JOIN LaundryServices ON Laundry_BillInfo.Id = LaundryServices.BillID INNER JOIN CheckIN_Room ON Laundry_BillInfo.CheckInID = CheckIN_Room.Cin_Id where Status='Checked Out' and Cin_ID=" & txtCheckInID.Text & " order by BillNo"
    MyCommand4.CommandText = "SELECT Room_OrderInfo.Id, Room_OrderInfo.BillNo, Room_OrderInfo.BillDate, Room_OrderInfo.CheckInId, Room_OrderInfo.GrandTotal, Room_OrderInfo.PaymentMode, Room_OrderInfo.TotalPayment,Room_OrderInfo.PaymentDue, Room_OrderInfo.Operator, Room_OrderInfo.RO_Status, Room_OrderedProduct.OP_Id, Room_OrderedProduct.BillID, Room_OrderedProduct.Dish_Liquor,Room_OrderedProduct.Volumn, Room_OrderedProduct.TakenFrom, Room_OrderedProduct.VATPer, Room_OrderedProduct.VATAmount, Room_OrderedProduct.STPer, Room_OrderedProduct.STAmount, Room_OrderedProduct.DiscountPer, Room_OrderedProduct.DiscountAmount, Room_OrderedProduct.Rate, Room_OrderedProduct.Quantity, Room_OrderedProduct.Amount, Room_OrderedProduct.TotalAmount,CheckIN_Room.Cin_Id, CheckIN_Room.GuestID, CheckIN_Room.RoomID, CheckIN_Room.RoomCharges, CheckIN_Room.DateIN, CheckIN_Room.DateOUT, CheckIN_Room.NoOfDays, CheckIN_Room.NoOfMales,CheckIN_Room.NoOfFemales, CheckIN_Room.NoOfKids, CheckIN_Room.NoOfExtraBed, CheckIN_Room.NoOfExtraPerson, CheckIN_Room.RoomOrderCharges, CheckIN_Room.ExtraPersonCharges, CheckIN_Room.TotalRoomCharges, CheckIN_Room.ExtraBedCharges, CheckIN_Room.OtherCharges, CheckIN_Room.DiscountPer AS Expr1, CheckIN_Room.DiscountAmount AS Expr2, CheckIN_Room.STPer AS Expr3, CheckIN_Room.STAmount AS Expr4, CheckIN_Room.LuxuryTaxPer, CheckIN_Room.LuxuryTaxAmount, CheckIN_Room.SubTotal, CheckIN_Room.GrandTotal AS Expr5, CheckIN_Room.TotalPaid, CheckIN_Room.Balance, CheckIN_Room.Status, CheckIN_Room.Notes FROM Room_OrderInfo INNER JOIN Room_OrderedProduct ON Room_OrderInfo.Id = Room_OrderedProduct.BillID INNER JOIN CheckIN_Room ON Room_OrderInfo.CheckInId = CheckIN_Room.Cin_Id where Status='Checked Out' and Cin_ID=" & txtCheckInID.Text & " order by BillNo"
    MyCommand5.CommandText = "SELECT * from Checkin_Payment where CheckInID =" & txtCheckInID.Text & ""
    MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    MyCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    MyCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    MyCommand3.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    MyCommand4.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    MyCommand5.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
    myDA1.SelectCommand = MyCommand1
    myDA2.SelectCommand = MyCommand2
    myDA3.SelectCommand = MyCommand3
    myDA4.SelectCommand = MyCommand4
    myDA5.SelectCommand = MyCommand5
    myDA.Fill(myDS, "Guest")
    myDA.Fill(myDS, "Room")
    myDA.Fill(myDS, "CheckIn_Room")
    myDA1.Fill(myDS, "Hotel")
    myDA2.Fill(myDS, "Currency")
    myDA3.Fill(myDS, "Laundry_BillInfo")
    myDA3.Fill(myDS, "LaundryServices")
    myDA4.Fill(myDS, "Room_OrderInfo")
    myDA4.Fill(myDS, "Room_OrderedProduct")
    myDA5.Fill(myDS, "Checkin_Payment")
    rpt.SetDataSource(myDS)
    rpt.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(myDS)
    rpt.Subreports(1).SetDataSource(myDS)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("v1", txtBillNo.Text)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("v2", dtpBillDate.Value)
    frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    frmReport.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Since you have many tables, my guess is that the problem is about the links between them. Maybe one of them is empty. Check your data.

Comment: What changed? You haven't specified where you ran the report when it worked and where it stopped working.